# General search: search between multiple collections (Express / mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Im new working with node, express and mongodb, so i don´t know if this is best way to implement this, i working in movie store ( Just for study and practicing ), where the is user is gonna have toolbar in the top with a search bar and is gonna be able to make a general search to find a movie/series/what ever else, now the way i was think i can implement this in `express` with `mongoose` was this way:

```
router.post('/search', (req, res) => {
  let resultSearch = [];
  Movie.find({ name: { $regex: req.body.query, $options: 'i' } })
    .then(movies => {
      if (movies.length > 0) {
        const moviesSearch = movies.map(movie => {
          return {
            _id: movie._id,
            content_type: movie.content_type,
            rate: movie.rate,
            name: movie.name,
            item_img: movie.movie_img,
            itemType: 'movies'
          };
        });
        resultSearch = [...moviesSearch];
      }
      Serie.find({ name: { $regex: req.body.query, $options: 'i' } }).then(series => {
        if (series.length > 0) {
          const seriesSearch = series.map(serie => {
            return {
              _id: serie._id,
              content_type: serie.content_type,
              rate: serie.rate,
              name: serie.name,
              item_img: serie.serie_img,
              itemType: 'series'
            };
          });
          resultSearch = [...resultSearch, ...seriesSearch];
        }
        res.status(200).send(resultSearch);
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).send(error);
    });
});
```

so the idea here is to search between multiple collections, as you can see here what im doing is just search in one collection, in the response of the promise make the search in the other collection. Now i completely sure that is not a good way to do it, in the case that i want to search between 10 different collection is gonna be a really messy code, so is there a better way to achieve this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ as it seeks to find the best ways of writing code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an array contain Models you want to find in and names(because your `img` field is based on the name) then loop through it and find with `async/await`:

```
router.post('/search', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let resultSearch = [];
    let sets = [{model: Movie, name: 'movie'}, {model: Serie, name: 'serie'}, ...some more];
    for (let set of sets) {
      let results = await set.model.find({ name: { $regex: req.body.query, $options: 'i' } });
      results = results.map(result => {
        return {
          _id: result._id,
          content_type: result.content_type,
          rate: result.rate,
          name: result.name,
          item_img: result[`${set.name}_img`],
          itemType: set.name //or you can use set.model.collection.collectionName
        };
      })
      resultSearch = resultSearch.concat(results);
    }
    res.status(200).send(resultSearch);
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
})
```

**Update:** As AZ_ suggest, using `Promise.all` and then map the output to be expected response will give better performance:

```
router.post('/search', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let sets = [{model: Movie, name: 'movie'}, {model: Serie, name: 'serie'}, ...some more];
    let resultSearch = await Promise.all(sets.map(set => set.model.find({ name: { $regex: req.body.query, $options: 'i' } }).exec()));
    resultSearch = resultSearch.map((results, i) => {
      return results.map(result => {
        return {
          _id: result._id,
          content_type: result.content_type,
          rate: result.rate,
          name: result.name,
          item_img: result[`${sets[i].name}_img`],
          itemType: sets[i].name //or you can use sets[i].model.collection.collectionName
        };
      })
    }
    res.status(200).send(resultSearch.flat());  //resultSearch is 2D array so need to flatten it
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
})
```

Comment: this way it will create an [Async Hell](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/avoiding-the-async-await-hell-c77a0fb71c4c/)

Comment: Yes, you're right.  After that it still need another loop to map the output to be expected response.

Comment: yes, but all the queries will be sent at the same time. so say if 1 query is taking 5 sec and you are creating an async hell it will take a total of `5*number of queries sec` however using `promise.all` it will take only 5 sec.

Comment: @AZ_ thanks so much for the contribution and you are completely right with `Promise.all` is faster.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Promise.all` rather chaining promises when there's no dependency.

```js
let moviesPromise = Movie.find({ name: { $regex: req.body.query, $options: 'i' } });
let seriesPromise = Serie.find({ name: { $regex: req.body.query, $options: 'i' } });
Promise.all([moviesPromise, seriesPromise]).then((res) => {
  arr = ['movies', 'series'];
  res.map((e, i)) => {
 e.map(obj => {
   return {
  _id: obj._id,
  content_type: obj.content_type,
  rate: obj.rate,
  name: obj.name,
  item_img: obj.[`${arr[i]}_img`],
  itemType: arr[i]
   };
 });
  })
```